# Minor bug in plain-text to HTML conversion using Regular Expressions

Tags: c#, html, regex, visual-studio-2010

I am facing a minor bug when doing the conversion from plain text to HTML. What might be the reason for this?

**Input:** (plain-text)

```
this is test input.
```

**Output:** (virtual plain-text but HTML)

```
   this is test input.
```

**BUG:** Moves one or two spaces forward. I have no clue why is this happening.

**Code for your reference**

```
string Text = "<html><body><pre style=\"font-family:consolas;font-size:88%;\">" 
    + mailItem.Body + "</pre></body></html>";

mailItem.HTMLBody = Text;          
mailItem.HTMLBody = Regex.Replace(mailItem.HTMLBody, 
    "(ASA[a-z][a-z][0-9][0-9])", "<a href=\"http://stack.com/eg=$&\">$&</a>");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested the following, and it works (eg. no spaces at beginning of output):

```
string mailItemBody = "ASAss87";
string oldText = "<html><body><pre style=\"font-family:consolas;font-size:88%;\">"
    + mailItemBody + "</pre></body></html>";

string newText = Regex.Replace(
    oldText, "(ASA[a-z][a-z][0-9][0-9])", "<a href=\"http://stack.com/eg=$&\">$&</a>");

Console.WriteLine("Old text is: \n\n" + oldText + "\n\n");
Console.WriteLine("New text is: \n\n" + newText + "\n\n");
```

I would investigate the class used to instantiate `mailItem`, and review at the `HTMLBody` property to see if anything funny is happening there.